# How to define a Tire property of type nested in a ActiveRecord mapping block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

I have a Rails application where a topic can be followed by various users. I want to be able to find a topic matching a name and followed by a specific user. Only using a Tire `query` statement, without a `filter`.

For that I intend to use [a boolean query with a nested query](http://karmi.github.io/tire/#section-Nested_Documents_and_Queries).

Here is my Topic model:

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks

  mapping do
    indexes :name
    indexes :follower_ids, type: 'nested', as: "indexed_follower_ids", id: 'integer'
  end
  def indexed_follower_ids
    followers.pluck(:id).map { |id| {id: id} }.to_json
  end

  attr_accessible :name

end
```

The Follow model contains

```
after_save :update_topic_index
def update_topic_index
  topic.tire.update_index
end
```

Unfortunately, after seeding my database with a few records, nothing is indexed. For instance if I create the following records:

```
User.create! name: "user0"
Topic.create! name: "topic0"
Follow.create! user: User.first, topic: Topic.first
```

I see the following errors in the ElasticSearch server logs:

```
[2013-04-16 15:07:28,564][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Sligguth] [topics] creating index, cause [api], shards [5]/[1], mappings [topic]
[2013-04-16 15:07:28,690][DEBUG][action.index             ] [Sligguth] [topics][2], node[UdT6jTecRNuzdRkxkX2uUA], [P], s[STARTED]: Failed to execute [index {[topics][topic][1], source[{"name":"topic0","follower_ids":"[]"}]}]
org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: object mapping for [topic] tried to parse as object, but got EOF, has a concrete value been provided to it?
at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.parse(ObjectMapper.java:457)
at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:494)
at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:438)
at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.service.InternalIndexShard.prepareIndex(InternalIndexShard.java:308)
at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportIndexAction.java:202)
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction.performOnPrimary(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:532)
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction$1.run(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:430)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
[2013-04-16 15:07:28,709][DEBUG][action.index             ] [Sligguth] [topics][2], node[UdT6jTecRNuzdRkxkX2uUA], [P], s[STARTED]: Failed to execute [index {[topics][topic][1], source[{"name":"topic0","follower_ids":"[{\"key_id\":1}]"}]}]
org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: object mapping for [topic] tried to parse as object, but got EOF, has a concrete value been provided to it?
at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.parse(ObjectMapper.java:457)
at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:494)
at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:438)
at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.service.InternalIndexShard.prepareIndex(InternalIndexShard.java:308)
at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportIndexAction.java:202)
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction.performOnPrimary(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:532)
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction$1.run(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:430)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Any idea why ElasticSearch fails on indexing my nested `follower_ids`?

Comment: Looking at your code snippet for `Follow.create! user: User.first, topic: Topic.first` , you appear to be referencing the User class, not an object instance. Should you be saying `u0 = User.create! name: "user0";
t0 = Topic.create! name: "topic0"; Follow.create! user: u0, topic: t0;` -- or something similar?

Comment: no, `User.first` returns a User object instance, so it's fine

Comment: Guess I don't know Tire well enough to really help then. Have you managed to get the same server to index non-Nested documents, or individual documents related through a _parent attribute?

Comment: You could just store it as an array as you only want to put the id there anyways, right?

Comment: Phil: yes, indexing works for non nested documents.

Comment: Yeggeps: that's what I did initially but I was not able to query on an array. I had tried `indexes :follower_ids, type: 'string', as: "indexed_follower_ids"` with `def indexed_follower_ids; followers.pluck :id; end` but `must { terms :indexed_follower_ids, [follower_id]}` would return only matching documents having a single follower. For instance a document having `[1, 2]` in `indexed_follower_ids` was not found when querying with `follower_id = 1`, while a document having `[1]` in indexed_follower_ids` is found. Maybe I did something wrong when trying to index and query on an array?

Comment: I just answered below before I saw this. This is definitely the approach you want to take, you probably want to specify the term query in a filter instead of putting it in a boolean query

Answer (score 0):

I imagine its because you're not storing an actual nested object in there, you're storing an array. just change the type for follower_ids to string and you should be okay.

edit: Just saw the thread above, when querying for the follower_ids, use a filter instead of specifying the terms query in a boolean and see how that works out